# AppleScript "translit" function

Tags: applescript, transliteration, cyrillic

I'm trying to find a solution to write Russian, but with latin characters (see the idea translit.ru)

My idea is to write an AppleScript smth like: -> selected text -> translit it

Hpw dp I work with a string in ActionScript replacing character by character?

Answer (score 1):

Transferring Latin with Cyrillic characters pops a first important question. Is it Unicode or is it also a transfer between Latin and Cyrillic character encodings?

You've asked for an example to replace character by character I can give you an example on how it can work. There are of course many other examples but here you can alter the sourcelist and targetlist to your likings.

```
set theString to "Hello World!"
set sourceList to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set targetList to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

set newString to {}
repeat with theChar in theString
    set o to offset of theChar in sourceList
    if o is 0 then
        set end of newString to contents of theChar
    else
        set end of newString to character o of targetList
    end if
end repeat
return newString as string
```